# Position fixed changes with filters

Tags: css

I have a fixed position element at the bottom of the page `bottom: 0` with a background colour of `black`. It's a navigation element that has things scrolling behind it.

I'm trying to do a stained glass effect using `backdrop-filter: blur(20px)` so I need to change the opacity of the `background-color`: `rgba(18,18,18,0.3)`.

When I add the filter change, the fixed element goes up `1px`, which means I can see a pixel of the things scrolling at the bottom of the page.

Why is this happening? 
What can I do to prevent/fix this?

Thanks in advance!

```css
.myDialog {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);

    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; 
}

body {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDialog">
 I don't disappear when you scroll!
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>aksldjnaskjdnaksjdnakjsdnakjnsdkajsndakjsndkajsndkjasndkjasndkjandkjanskdjnaskdjnaskjdnakjsdnakjsndkajndkjasndkjansd<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

(there's a piece of text that when you scroll through, you see it behind the fixed box).

https://jsfiddle.net/379heofx/2/ (in case code above doesn't show, which boggles my mind even further)

screenshot of issue:
[image: You can see the text below the whiteish box, which should be stuck to the bottom]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: please can you create a [mcve] otherwise we cannot help you -  as far as I know, changing the background colour to use rgba would not move the element

Comment: added JS fiddle

Comment: Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted, or as an executable stack snippet, in cases where that makes sense - not just dropped onto an external platform.

Comment: (Also, your fiddle does not seem to reproduce the effect you are describing, at least in Chrome I can’t see it happening.)

Comment: updated with snippet. sorry for all the mess. I can see the issue on chrome :|

Answer (score -1):

You can try and use the `opacity` keyword instead.

So like this:

```
yourelement {
   background-color: black;
   opacity: 0.3
}
```

Comment: wont work unfortunately. did some digging and filters mess with fixed positioned elements, but cant find this kind of behaviour described anywhere.